# Updating .net on all machines in the same domain?

Tags: windows, deployment, chef, sccm

I have a ton of machines without internet (~100). I need to update powershell/.net on all of them. They all lie within the same domain. What is the best option? I don't have anything like Chef or SCCM preconfigured on these machines.

Answer (score 3):

You surelly have an internal WSUS server. Please approve the KB for those computers to update powershell and .net, keep it simple